# Why angular frequency doesn't changed?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves, frequency, string

> Suppose a wave is moving on a uniform string, let at $x=0$ rate of energy transfer is $P_o$, with amplitude $A_o$, angular frequency $\omega_o$. Then gradually rate of energy transfers become $\frac{P_o}{2}$ at $x=l$, then my book says $\omega_o$ should not change, also $A_o\rightarrow \frac{A_o}{\sqrt{2}}$.

What I think is, a string is a uniform hence $v=\sqrt{\frac{F}{\mu}}$ everywhere, which should imply $\lambda\nu=v=constant$, hence on LHS **both** $\lambda,\nu$ should change or **both** does not change, for $\omega_o=2\pi\nu$ to be constant later should hold, means $\nu\rightarrow$ constant, but as energy is changed so frequency should also change (I think), but it doesn't, why?

Why is the change in power compensated solely by Amplitude($A_o$)?

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Think about what it would mean for the frequency to change as the wave is passed along the string by means of forces between particles. It would mean that cycles of oscillation would have to disappear or be added as the wave moved along. This is unphysical... Suppose that at *x* = 0 the frequency were 20 Hz (20 cycles per second); how could there be only 19 cycles per second at $x=l$? How could a cycle of oscillation have got lost, and (to emphasise the silliness)  *which* cycle would it be? Or how could there be 21 cycles per second at $x=l$? Whereabouts in the sequence of cycles entering the string at $x=0$ would the extra cycle be inserted, and by what means?